# Finding lambda captured values (or their classes) in Scala 3

Tags: scala, lambda, closures, scala-3, dotty

I'm looking for a way to find values (or their classes) that are captured by lambda (for serialization - something like Spark) in Scala 3 (I don't need Scala 2 support):

```
val a = "abc"
val f = () => a + "xyz"
serialize(f) // Should detect a / String as captured value
```

Doing this in runtime is kinda easy (iterating over `f.getClass.getDeclaredFields`), but I would like to do it in compile time.

I was trying to inspect time of lambda in Macro, but it's detected as plain `scala.Function0` without any interesting info.

I wonder if I can do some tree inspection, but I would really like to avoid that - I feel like I would have to copy compiler internals to catch all edge cases.

Comment: *"Doing this in runtime is kinda easy"* Not sure how `f.getClass.getDeclaredFields` can help with detecting `a`. I guess the output is the same with `a` and without `a` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/ZVHSyWTDTduIlTRorzEHIA

Comment: I guess in a macro you can traverse the tree of lambda twice. First time collecting symbols of `val` definitions. And second time checking whether identifiers refer to the definitions from the first step.

Comment: So you'll be able to differentiate `a` and `x` in `val f = () => { val x = "uvw"; a + x + "xyz"}`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin The issue with tree parsing is that there could be "import ExternalLibrary.PublicStaticValues.a" before the lambda. I must check if it's possible to check in macro where variable is coming from.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. In the case of such import you'll not have the `a` in the first step so you'll know that `a` is from an outer scope (like `val a = "abc"` or `import ExternalLibrary.PublicStaticValues.a`). Or do you want to differentiate the cases `val a = "abc"` and `import ExternalLibrary.PublicStaticValues.a`?

Comment: Yeah, but not all outer scope variables are treated equally. Static variables are not added to captured values - which is fine by me.

Comment: I've created test case with more cases: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QknCqi52Qhm67tWLNQId7w - your test case is implicitly in class constructor and it messes a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html)

```scala
import scala.quoted.*

inline def serialize(x: Any): Unit = ${serializeImpl('x)}

def serializeImpl(x: Expr[Any])(using Quotes): Expr[Unit] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  def owners(s: Symbol): List[Symbol] = s :: List.unfold(s)(s1 => Option.when(s1.maybeOwner != Symbol.noSymbol)((s1.maybeOwner, s1.maybeOwner)))

  val symbol = x.asTerm.underlying.symbol
  val rhs = symbol.tree match {
    case ValDef(_, _, Some(rhs)) => rhs
  }

  val traverser = new TreeTraverser {
    override def traverseTree(tree: Tree)(owner: Symbol): Unit = {
      tree match {
        case Ident(name) =>
          val symbol1 = tree.symbol
          val pos1 = symbol1.pos.get
          println(s"identifier: $name, defined inside lambda: ${owners(symbol1).contains(symbol)}, defined in current file: ${pos1.sourceFile == SourceFile.current}")

        case _ =>
      }

      super.traverseTree(tree)(owner)
    }
  }

  traverser.traverseTree(rhs)(rhs.symbol)

  '{()}
}
```

Usage:

```scala
object App1 {
  val b = "bbb"
}
```

```scala
import App1.b

object App {
  val a = "abc"
  val f = () => { val x = "uvw"; a + b + x + "xyz"}
  serialize(f)
}

//scalac: identifier: a, defined inside lambda: false, defined in current file: true
//scalac: identifier: b, defined inside lambda: false, defined in current file: false
//scalac: identifier: x, defined inside lambda: true, defined in current file: true
//scalac: identifier: $anonfun, defined inside lambda: true, defined in current file: true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, unfortunately it does not compile in my project for some reason and it seems to be binded to `val` in object scope. However thanks to `owners` method and traverseTree I'm currently working on solution that would match my project requirements.

Comment: @Andrew For convenience, I published the project at https://github.com/DmytroMitin/scala3-macro-closure-demo If your compile error is `MatchError` because the AST in right hand side of `val` definition is empty then most probably you are missing `scalacOptions += "-Yretain-trees"`. If you still experience compile errors and need assistance please provide reproduction (in this or a new question).